# How to retrieve name from Active Directory and store in a custom list?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm writing a polling app for Sharepoint 2013. I created a custom list and need to save the user's vote for each poll.

How do I pass in the Active Directory Name into a label control on the app?

Comment: AD name? Will the spuser be enough? then you can use the currentuser from web context

Comment: You get all you need from the user object. If you don't like to code you can simply use a survey list that does the same as your application.

Comment: @Burrhus Can you elaborate further in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

```
this.currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

this.currentUser = this.currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();

this.currentContext.load(this.currentUser);

this.currentContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

onQuerySucceeded = function () {
        var intCount = 1;
        $(".ms-inputuserfield").html(this.currentUser.get_loginName());        
};
```

The code isn't tested but you get the idea I think.